# Wrapping an angular-ui directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm trying to create a wrapper around the `tab` angular-ui bootstrap directive.

My custom directive is;

```
myMoudule.directive('tabWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        compile: function compileFn(element, attrs) {
            element.replaceWith(
                '<tab heading="' + attrs.heading  + '"></tab>'
            );
        }
    };
});
```

The usage is:

```
<tabset>
    <tab-wrapper heading="Page 1"></tab-wrapper>
    <tab-wrapper heading="Page 2"></tab-wrapper>
</tabset>
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ALBiIWJbLXK0QzKNu0j6?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use link function instead

```
myMoudule.directive('tabWrapper', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        replace: true,
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs) {
           var html = '<tab heading="' + attrs.heading  + '"></tab>';
           var e = $compile(html)(scope);
           element.replaceWith(e);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to include the inner html `var html = '<tab heading="' + attrs.heading  + '">'+element.html()+'</tab>';` and it works perfectly.

Comment: A follow up question is does is incur a performance penalty to call `$compile` in the linking function (doesn't it kind of defeats the purpose of the compilation and linking separation)?

Comment: @tepez I think in terms of the performance, they are pretty much same. `compile` function is not often used though.

Comment: There is still a problem. `ng-repeat` on the `tab-wrapper` is being ignored. Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/ReHzcWlJMM0e0HUjvl2j. Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 2):

for usage with ng-repeat you need to use the compile function instead of the link function.
the compile function creates the "base"-template-DOM which gets duplicated by ng-repeat.

```
myMoudule.directive('tabWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        replace: true,
        compile:  function(element, attrs) {
            var html = '<tab heading="' + attrs.heading  + '"></tab>';
            var e = angular.element(html);
            element.replaceWith(e);
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/YxBuYmJkbGKuwYN90H1b